# C# code validation in Silverlight GUI

Tags: c#, silverlight, user-interface, user-controls

I'm making a Silverlight app for students and I'm looking for a key component. In the application, the students should be able to add C# code (one class) in a text box. What I would like to do, is to: Validate that the code is valid C# and ideally also make sure it correctly implements a given interface. Is there a control out there which can help me with this?

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to conclude and answer my own question (thanks to Luke Woodward): This isn't possible as the System.CodeDom.Compiler namespace is just about empty in the Silverlight framework :-(

Answer (score 1):

Example Code based on the [CodecomProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    CodeDomProvider codeProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
    string Output = "Out.exe";
    Button ButtonObject = (Button)sender;

    textBox2.Text = "";
    System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
    //Make sure we generate an EXE, not a DLL
    parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
    parameters.OutputAssembly = Output;
    CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, textBox1.Text);

    if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
    {
        textBox2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        foreach (CompilerError CompErr in results.Errors)
        {
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text +
                        "Line number " + CompErr.Line +
                        ", Error Number: " + CompErr.ErrorNumber +
                        ", '" + CompErr.ErrorText + ";" +
                        Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Successful Compile
        textBox2.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        textBox2.Text = "Success!";
        //If we clicked run then launch our EXE
        if (ButtonObject.Text == "Run") Process.Start(Output);
    }
}
Add the beginning of the file, add these using statements:
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Comment: Looks good. But I have a question: This seems to create an actual file - it is possible to do this just in memory? I just want to validate - not run this code at this point.

Comment: What do you mean validate? i assume if it compiles then its a valid code ! so if you save this to a temporary file which you override each time would this be an option?

Comment: as far as i know if you do not specify a file name for the output assembly in the OutputAssembly property a default output file name will be used.

Comment: Well, the problem that might be there, is that this is going to run in a Silverlight application which doesn't need file access for any other reason, so this would complicate things... Also, file I/O is slower than doing it all in memory.

Comment: This does not work in Silverlight.  The only class Silverlight has under `System.CodeDom.Compiler` is `GeneratedCodeAttribute`.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler%28v=vs.95%29.aspx